# C#/WPF Resize Window to MediaElement's Original Content size

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, mediaelement

I have a Window which a dynamically size with it's content (MediaElement).

For this I use a Window with the Attribute `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`.
My MediaElement is set like this `Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="DownOnly"`.

With those Settings the Window will be as big as the original size of the MediaElement Control. But Stretching is set to DownOnly and I'd like the possibility to make the window bigger.
But when i set the Attribute StretchDirection to Both, the Window will be Maximized when I load another Movie with MediaElement.

I would like that the Window has the Size of the MediaElement, but when I make the Window bigger I want that the MediaElement is getting bigger too.

Thanks for your help in advance!

This is the WPF Window

```
<base:ContentWindow x:Class="ExplorerExtension.WindowsMediaWindow" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:base="clr-namespace:ExplorerExtension" ShowActivated="False" 
WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement x:Name="MediaEL" MediaOpened="MediaEL_MediaOpened"
                  LoadedBehavior="Manual" Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="DownOnly"/>
    </Grid>
</base:ContentWindow>
```

And the Code

```
    public WindowsMediaWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MediaEL.Source = new Uri("---");
    }
```

[image: Picture of the Window]

Note: All Videos have different sizes, so I can't set a fixed Width or Height

Comment: A visual example will explain the problem more clearly

Comment: @Shaharyar Added one, i hope it helps to understand the question

Comment: Yup, I am trying to re create the scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry I could not identify the reason of your problem. But here is a solution of it.

**Solution:**

Set `StretchDirection="DownOnly"` by the start, but as you change the size of the window, set it to `UpOnly`.

**Technical Description:**

To do this, you'll have to subscribe to the `SizeChanged` event of the `Window`. But the problem is, this event also fires at the startup of the application. So you'll have to subscribe to that event after loading the window.

So, first of all subscribe to the `Loaded` event of the window and in that event handler, subscribe to the `SizeChanged` event:

**XAML (in window tag):**

```
Loaded="Window_Loaded"
```

**C#:**

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaEL.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.UpOnly;
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.SizeChanged += Window_SizeChanged;
}
```

You can also refer to [this](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/stretchdirection/) article, it defines `StretchDirection` with very nice examples.

Comment: Thank you @Shaharyar. This was the way i could solve my problem. It's a pity that there's no better solution for this. I changed my code to dynamically change media files I play, i will try to post a working solution in the next days if someone wants to achieve the same.